# como puedo importar la libreria slidingmenu de Jeremy Feinstein en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Necesito agregar la libreria slidingmenu de Jeremy Feinstein que descargue de github en el android studio y no se como ya que como es un comprimido no se como agregar ese tipo de librerias.Saludos

Comment: No se si conoces la librería de Google support library, que te puede ofrecer de forma nativa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057367/exact-procedure-to-add-jfeinstein10-slidingmenu-in-android-project

Comment: en este [enlace](https://sintaxispragmatica.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/anadir-librerias-jar-en-androidstudio/) te enseñan como añadir librerias a android studio

Answer (score 3):

Si deseas incluir esta librería en un proyecto empezarías a incluir código obsoleto por ejemplo necesitarías [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) que también es obsoleto.

Para agregar la librería [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), simplemente agrega el .jar dentro de tu folder `/libs`. si es un .zip descomprimelo importalo a tu workspace y en tu proyecto agrégalo y marcalo como librería (isLibrary).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057367/exact-procedure-to-add-jfeinstein10-slidingmenu-in-android-project

Actualmente no veo como opción usar la librería SlidingMenu si ya se tiene **[Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)**. En pocas palabras crearías una bola de nieve agregando código obsoleto que al final tendrías que cambiar!

Aquí tienes un tutorial para implementar  **[Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)**:
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/11/android-navigation-drawer-tutorial/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]